# Jump when the screen is tapped, rather than when the space key is pressed

Tags: unity, c#, touch

I am trying to make my character jump when the player taps the screen.

At the moment it jumps when I press space bar, but how can I change the code to make him jump when the screen is tapped?

This code works as the character then jumps up:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        rb.gravityScale *= -1;
    }
}
```

This code using touch does not work: the character just stays where he is when I click the screen on my computer.

```
public void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        rb.gravityScale *= -1;
    }        
}
```

Comment: Make jump with which button? There are many types of buttons

Comment: Just one button on the entire screen similar to flappy bird.

Comment: Presumably you considered using [Input.touchCount](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-touchCount.html) to detect when the screen has been touched?

Comment: Please see above the input.touchcount I used as it still did not work.

Comment: @DMGregory I have included my jump code that works with the spacebar but not with the touch count.

Comment: In what sense did it "not work"? The contents of your if statement are different in each case, so we'll need more details on the exact differences in the code you're using, and the exact differences in behaviour.

Comment: In the sense that in the initial code that says if you press the spacebar then the character will do an action, but then when I change the space bar if statement to the touch count if statement then the character just stays where he is and does nothing.

Comment: @DMGregory I have shown both codes as they are.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to debounce the press. GetKeyDown will be true for exactly one frame. TouchCount can stay greater than zero as long as there's a finger on the screen. So you need to check if touchCount *increased* since last frame, or if the touch phase is "began"

Comment: @DMGregory I added a debug.log("I am pressed") to the end of the touch count code and nothing comes up in the console.

Comment: And you're testing this on a touch-enabled device? What's your current testing setup?

Comment: I am testing it by clicking the screen on my computer, does that not do the same thing?

Comment: Or did you mean you want mouse clicks (unlike Flappy Bird)? If so, you tried using GetMouseButtonDown, right?

Comment: No I want a touch device to be able to do it but I thought you could use the touch count with a mouse button press too, is that not the case?

Comment: I have resolved the issue, thanks!!!!

Comment: If you've solved your problem, please post your solution as an Answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the code to the following by adding a TouchPhase.Began to the if statement:

```
public void Update()
{


    if (Input.touchCount == 1)
    {
        if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

            rb.gravityScale *= -1;

        }
    }


}
```

Then testing it on a device using unity remote.